# Python requests как войти в инстаграм и остаться там

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, instagram

помогите пожалуйста, хочу понять как с помощью requests войти в инстаграм и остаться там?

Напишите пожалуйста пример

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у Инсты нет открытого API для клиентских приложений, чтобы можно было зайти :) Есть [Basic API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) для извлечения базовой инфы и [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) для бизнес-аккаунтов. Хотя некоторые особо нуждающиеся реверс-инженерят клиентское АПИ, но об этом вам здесь вряд ли расскажут.